# Can the "Damaging" Extra be turned off for Move Object's effect?

Tags: powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm using the Portuguese version of the 3rd edition. The general rule for Extras is that they can't be turned off, changing the power effects permanently. But the Damaging Extra describes that '*your effect **can** inflict damage...*'

Should I assume that this Extra can be turned off? The 2nd edition was more clear regarding this since you had Feats (on/off) and Extras (always on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, But ...

Your confusion comes from ignoring half of the sentence.

> Your effect can inflict damage, like an application of normal Strength with damage equal to its rank.

When using *Move Object* with the damaging extra, it can be used like Strength to deal damage equal to the effect rank.
The *Move Object* effect isn't made of fire, or similar automatic damage, it simply has the ability to crush or punch like it was normal Strength.

Comment: So, if I apply Damaging Extra to Move Object, I can only use it to cause damage like using Strength to the same purpose?

Comment: @BrunoEstrazulas Yep. Which is a function it doesn't normally have, essentially giving you a Strength with the Ranged extra. You can move stuff, punch stuff, grapple, all from as far as your range allows.

Comment: Just to clarify that answer, you don't have to do Damage, just like when you use Strength. :) If you wanted that to happen, you could create a Reaction Damage effect, kind of like an "Energy Aura" triggered by touching (or being touched by) the telekinesis.